# `JsonSerializable` with base classes

Tags: dart

Having the following classes:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Person {
  final String name;
  Person({required this.name});
  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}
```

```
@JsonSerializable()
class Taxable {
  final String taxNumber;
  Person({required this.taxNumber});
  factory Taxable(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TaxableFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TaxableToJson(this);
}
```

What's the best approach to create a `TaxablePerson` that both extends `Taxable` and `Person` and supports JSON serialisation?

Making `TaxablePerson implements Taxable, Person` requires to again declare all the inherited fields.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a better way to do that with just dart and `json_serializable`. you could work with [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) unions instead of inheritance to achieve a similar result with more code generation and less manual copying.